# How does a filter mesh/scotch-brite increase the thickness of the foam in foam spray?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics

On YouTube there are a lot of videos that show how to make a foam spray from a simple garden spray. One example you may see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKUX5H7-xu0

(5:55 point is the most relevant for my question).

They make that by piercing a small hole in the small tube (which in general, is used to suck the water from the bottle and they add a piece of aquarium filter or a piece of scotch brite (which is more common used like in this video)inside the nozzle to increase the thickness of the foam. I know that the 3 base components to make a foam are: soap, water and air (besides other chemicals that can be added to the mixer to increase the foam formation),so i understand that the air which is mixing with the soap/water is making that foam, but how does the piece of aquarium filter/scotch brite inside the nozzle make the foam thicker?What is the engineering/science explanation behind that?

Comment: is it there to help break up the droplets? ie atomisation?

Comment: Think of blowing bubbles using soapy water and a hoop.  You form a membrane of soapy water in the hoop and stretch that membrane by blowing air through it.  The mesh is a cost effective way to have multiples of the hoop- you don't need big bubbles so much as you need many small ones.  The hoop is a holder of the membrane against the flow of air, much as a die is a holder of (sheet) metal against forces applied by a punch.

Comment: @Abel,So,besides the scotch brite and the aquarium filter,it sound like every material that is constructed with many tiny holes(pores) will make the same result(thick foam)Am i right?i was trying to use a regular sponge,which has alot of tiny holes,but it didn't work like with the scotch brite.What make the material,in this example,the scotch-brite,to be more effective in making a good thick foam compare to the regular sponge(which also has a lot of holes?

Comment: Regular sponge does not have the stiffness needed. Pressure closes and deforms it pretty easily, and the spring back when a bubble is released from the membrane does not help.  It, like paper is also absorbent and will stick to your fluid in a way that keeps more of the air out.  Materials with holes aren't that special; atoms are mostly empty space- but the right sized holes is different.  If you wish to use a regular sponge, you would have to soak it and squeeze it, alternating between air and soap; that way throughout the cycle, at least some of the holes are at the right condition.